# Postgres searching in a column splitted by regexp_split_to_table

Tags: postgresql, alias, where-clause

I have the following table:

```
cs_id ; cs_values ; cs_desc
---------------------------
     1;    'a,b,c';   'one'
     2;      'd,a';   'two'
     3;      'a,c'; 'three'
```

The field "cs_valies" contains different comma separeted values. I would like to get all "cs_id" on lines that contain a certain value in "cs_values".

I used this expression:

```
SELECT
   cs_id,
   regexp_split_to_table(cs_values, '* , *') as splitted_value
WHERE
   splitted_value = 'a'
```

I have to questions:

1. Postgres does not like alias names in the `WHERE`-clause. Or has anyone an idea how to achieve this?
2. Does anyone have a better idea to solve the given problem?

Thanks everybody, 
I hope I am not missing something extremly evident.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Postgres does not like alias names in the WHERE-clause. Or has anyone an idea how to achieve this?*

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT 
      cs_id,
      regexp_split_to_table(cs_values, '* , *') as splitted_value
) t
WHERE
   splitted_value = 'a'
```

> *Does anyone have a better idea to solve the given problem?*

Normalize your table and put the "comma separated list" into its own table with. This is a classical 1:n relation

Comment: Your definitly right, normalization would be the first thing I would do, if I had any influence on the given data... but I don't.

Comment: Never the less... your answer is great and helps a lot. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: I wonder who actually creates all those denormalized models out there. Each time I stumble upon one, the answer is "it was not done by me/us and I/we cannot change it". Very strange

Comment: Actually this is a CRM system, that can be customized. The client "implemented" some kind of "logic" into it. The logic consists of some fields where multiple values can be stored, separated by a comma. Although there a some datatypes which would fit, the customer abused a plain text field to enter multiple values.... Now there is absolutely no money there to change the data model, because to much stuff depends on it... but there is a lot of money there to build workarounds... thats where I come into play.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation on my hands.
Here's what I found works with pgsql:

```
select a.id, a.name from student as a, (select id, cast(regexp_split_to_table(topics, ',') as text) as topic from student) as b where a.id = b.id and b.topic = 'science';
```

Hope it helps you too.